# Import/Require nodejs modules without @types in Typescript in 2018

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import, require

I have a typescript nodejs project for a website. I need to use functionality that is available in this specific nodejs module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/weather-js

This module does not have a .d.ts file available in its repository, nor is there one available in the '@types' typescript repository. I do not require type definitions for this module, but typescript does not include it and produces errors.

No matter which way I try to import, I either get

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
```

in the build console, or

```
TypeError: qs.escape is not a function
```

in the browser dev console.

Many responses here on StackOverflow suggest solutions that require repositories that are no longer available in 2018, or that might work but for me still produce the error

```
TypeError: qs.escape is not a function
```

**What is the correct way to use/import/require/consume nodejs module functionality (without .d.ts definitions available) in typescript in 2018?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a dummy definition to allow it to import but without actually typing the module contents (although maybe if you should type them fully and submit to [DefinitlyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) so the everyone can benefit from type safety too!)

weather-js.d.ts

```
// declaring module will allow typescript to import the module
declare module 'weather-js' {
  // typing module default export as `any` will allow you to access its members without compiler warning
  var weatherJs: any; 
  export default weatherJs;
}
```

yourCode.ts

```
import weather from 'weather-js'

weather.find({search: 'San Francisco, CA', degreeType: 'F'}, () => {})
```

Comment: I created the weather-js.d.ts file in the same file as yourCode.ts. The project compiles, but the browser console says 
'TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined'

Comment: Well its strange it compiles if you added the module definition in the same file, as it then becomes module augmentation, but there is no existing module to augment so you should get compiler error `Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'weather-js' resolves to an untyped module`