# "Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module" error in signrequest-client angular

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I'm trying to implement signRequest API in my angular application.
For that I installed signrequest-client using command -

> npm install signrequest-client --save

After that I added following js code in component's .ts file -

```
var SignrequestClient = require('signrequest-client');

var defaultClient = SignrequestClient.ApiClient.instance;

// Configure API key authorization: Token
var Token = defaultClient.authentications["Token"];
Token.apiKey = "YOUR API KEY";
Token.apiKeyPrefix = "Token";

var api = new SignrequestClient.DocumentsApi();

var data = new SignrequestClient.Document();
data.file_from_url =
  "https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oI2R1SxfMNZXiz3jCQvorpoklF9xq_dCJnOpkI-zo80/edit?usp=sharing";

var callback = function(error, data, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.log("API called successfully. Returned data: " + data);
  }
};

api.documentsCreate(data, callback);
```

after running this file, it throwing an error on line **var SignrequestClient = require('signrequest-client');** says,

> ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ApiClient'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'api/ApiTokensApi'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'api/DocumentAttachmentsApi'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'api/DocumentsApi'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'api/DocumentsSearchApi'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'api/EventsApi'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'api/SignrequestQuickCreateApi'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'api/SignrequestsApi'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'api/TeamMembersApi'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'api/TeamsApi'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'api/TemplatesApi'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'api/WebhooksApi'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/AuthToken'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/Document'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/DocumentAttachment'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/DocumentSearch'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/DocumentSignerTemplateConf'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/DocumentSigningLog'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/DocumentSignrequest'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/DocumentTeam'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/Event'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/FileFromSf'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineDocumentSignerIntegrationData'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineIntegrationData'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlinePrefillTags'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineResponse200'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineResponse2001'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineResponse2002'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineResponse2003'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineResponse2004'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineResponse2005'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineResponse2006'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineResponse2007'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineResponse2008'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineResponse2009'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineResponse201'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineResponse2011'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineSignRequest'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineTeam'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InlineTeamMember'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/InviteMember'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/Placeholder'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/RequiredAttachment'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/SignRequest'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/SignRequestQuickCreate'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/Signer'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/SignerAttachment'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/SignerInputs'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/SigningLog'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/Team'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/TeamMember'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/Template'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/User'  m
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/signrequest-client/src/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/WebhookSubscription'

for above project, I was referring -
*https://www.npmjs.com/package/signrequest-client#installation*

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this section of the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/signrequest-client#webpack-configuration.
I think that this package does not have types so using it from typescript is a bit harder. What you can do is mock the definition.
See this stack overflow post to see how: [Import/Require nodejs modules without @types in Typescript in 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224858/import-require-nodejs-modules-without-types-in-typescript-in-2018)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to use that client, you can call the API directly, using 'superagent' for example. See this repo:

https://github.com/SignRequest/signrequest-Node-example